# SQL : how to compare 2 values and if they match return the one that is older than 3 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to make a report that 
compare the SKUs that are scheduled on the filling lines this week with how long it has been since the same SKU has been running on the line, and thus only those SKUs that have not been running (or have never been) for more than 3 months, displays.

edit : i think i need to write a query that finds the most recent date of every SKU number and then compare it to the SKU number that is used this week and then
show the ones that are older then 3 months. but i have no clue how to do this with keeping the code underneath intact ?

I have no clue how to start i searched and tried a lot but did not succeed

thanks in advance

code to het sku from this week:

`

```
SELECT 
od.odscheduleid
,lc.shortname as line
,ar.erpcode as SKU
,ar.shortname as Article
,od.[PlannedStartInflow]
,od.[PlannedEndInflow]
,st.shortname as 'status'
,od.[ShortName] as 'order'
,od.[ERPCode]
,od.[ASCode]
,od.[PlannedQuantity] as 'PlannedQuantity [PC]'
,cast(od.[PlannedQuantity]*ar.Volume/100 as decimal(12,2)) as 'PlannedQuantity [HL]'
,od.[PlannedChangeoverTime]
,od.[PlannedSpeed]
,od.[PlannedSpeedRatio]
  FROM [RM].[TblDatODSchedule] od
  inner join [EM].[TblLstLocation] lc on od.locationid=lc.locationid
  inner join [RM].[TblLstART] ar on od.artid=ar.artid
  inner join [EM].[TblLstStatus] st on od.statusid=st.statusid
 WHERE lc.locationid in (@Line) --lc.packagingtype is not null
 and plannedendinflow > @StartDate`
```

Comment: [mcve] is a good start!

Comment: use case statement in Sqlserver for this. It compare 2 or more column for each row level.

Comment: @Ajay2707 how would you do this without interfering with the original code ?

Comment: give some data and minimum column to work on

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's suppose you have a table such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE SKU (name varchar(50), last_run datetime);
```

We can make your query work like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SKU
WHERE last_run IS NULL
OR datediff(month, last_run, getdate()) > 3
```

Comment: hi thank you but that is only 1 part of the solution. now I need to compare the SKU'S that are used this week with the ones you just mentioned above , if both SKU's match and they are used longer then 3 months ago than i need to show the sku and the date

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you are saying. If they are used this week, how can they match something that hasn't been used for three months. I think of some questions. What is an SKU? Do there exists many records for each given SKU or only one? This and other clarifications are needed, such as the structure of your table, are there more than are record per SKU, a short example of expected output, etc.

Comment: Why is it that after we ask for more details people suddenly stop responding.

Comment: hi so we use reports that check which beer(sku) needs to be used this week for filling bottles. now the question i got was to make a report that checks if the beer(sku) that is used this week on the report isn't used for 3 months if so i need to show those beers(sku) on the report.  i am sorry i can't explain it better i will place some code that is used to get the sku's for this week.